# Nuxt js App working well locally but not on production in heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I developed a nuxt js/ vuetify and tailwindcss app that works perfectly on my local host but after deploying to heroku server, the app looks disorganized. No/irregular style.. Apis are not working. Below is my build script and screenshots of both local and heroku. Any help will be appreciated

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build"
  },
```

[This is the screenshot on my local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLCoI.png)

[Screenshot of app in heroku server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB7g3.png)

Comment: Did you get any error on console like `Failed to load resource...`

Comment: No error... this is the message i got       -----> Build succeeded!
 !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
       https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 49.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://theleadbtc.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Comment: Could you share your repo url ?

Comment: here is it https://github.com/Kingo4luv/theleadbtc

Comment: Why didn't you import your router to `server/index.js` ?

Comment: I have made lot of changes lately on the project trying to see if it will work.. the router was actually moved to nuxt.config after checking out the documentation.. it also worked locally

Comment: @ahmet zeybek.. i will appreciate any help.. Apis are working well after removing procfile.. But the style is the main issue

Comment: I am getting dashboardPosts error now, did you disabled mongo server ?

Comment: okay.. Thanks.. i will wait... Am suspecting vuetify is the cause.. because tailwindcss styles are visible

Comment: No currently dashboardPost isnt available.. only on local host

Comment: I looked almost every line but I didn't see any problem. As you said vuetify and tailwind are in collision. I removed tailwind then vuetify worked without problem... Changed tailwind prefixes in all components then added, but I got same problem again. Sorry I did everything, but you should choose one of them

Comment: Ok.. thanks so much